# how to always show TextView text above keyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview

I have a Textview that's covered partially by the keyboard when it shows. As a result, the text which entered into the space covered by the keyboard can not be seen as it is typed. 
How do I make the TextView scroll up when the entered text reached the space covered by the keyboard?

I have scroll enabled on the TextView but since all the text is visible on the screen , the vertical scroll bar is not visible. Can I have the vertical scroll bar visible at all time event when editing?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)
 library.

> IQKeyboardManager works on all orientations, and with the toolbar.
>   There are also nice optional features allowing you to customize the
>   distance from the text field, add the next/previous done button as a
>   keyboard UIToolbar, play sounds when the user navigations through the
>   form and more.

Comment: That look great, thanks! But I would like something simpler just for this use case not a whole framework

Comment: I use IQKeyboardManager and works perfectly for me. It's very easy with cocoapod. Highly suggest this library since coding to show the keyboard everytime is actually really hard.